# How can I make an oversized chalkboard organiser?

Tags: tags

I found this ( http://www.pbteen.com/products/oversized-chalkboard-organization/ ) on PB Teens and Pinterest and fell in love. It's perfect for me but at a price of around £200 is a bit ridiculous! Anybody got any ideas on how I might DIY this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a subject completely unrelated to Craft or website development.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely use a custom Element Type.

Comment: I'd like to move this question and answer into some Craft SE hall-of-fame page.

Comment: Ever since Craft SE opened up, I've been waiting for someone to post about their random crafts project. That day has finally come... and your perfect response has exceeded my expectations. Bravo sir, bravo.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely gotta have a chalkboard font as well:

http://www.fontspace.com/category/chalkboard

;)